# Is it possible to redirect NATs Jetstream message to Elastic search

Tags: filebeat, elk, nats.io, efk, nats-jetstream

We use NATS Jetstream for message distribution.
I want to display messages delivered to Nats in UI. All message have pre defined common structure.

Do we have file beat or logstash plugin to read the content (message) of NATS and redirect to ES. Or any other mechanism to redirect the content to ES and use Kibana.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [vector](https://vector.dev/docs/reference/configuration/) for this purpose. Use a nats source and a elasticsearch sink should work